# SQLite data gone disappeared after restarting app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I just wanted to know about the following code. Is the disappearing related with the file path or not? Explanation would be great.

```
public Database(Context context)
{
    String path = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    dbHelper = new mSQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   clearTable();
}
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me (without knowing more about the logical flow--when is `Database` call?) is that in order to get the object `db` you are doing this :: `if (file.exists()) { file.delete(); }` and then you call `clearTable()`. That seems like that might just delete the file!! and delete any data from the `DB_TABLE_NAME` table!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create an instance of Database the first thing you do is delete the existing database i.e. :-

```
String path = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
File file = new File(path);
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

You then continue and create the database with :-

```
dbHelper = new mSQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
clearTable();
```

I'd suggest removing the first statements that find the path and delete the database file. i.e. that use :-

```
public Database(Context context)
{
    dbHelper = new mSQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    clearTable();
}
```